# How create a form based on {Placeholders} gotten from a html file in another directory

Tags: php, html, forms

Please note i am very new to PHP and this is my first app, Any information you can provide me would be greatly appreciated. This was hard to explain without giving heaps of code and diagrams so hope this is enough?

Say i have 3-6 template .html files in a folder(s) called /templates/template_name/index.html like below but with different placeholders: `{thisthing}`

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>{page_meta_title}</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
</head> 
<body> 
<div class="content-wrap">
<h3>{header}</h3>
<p>{page_text}</p>
<a href="{link_url}">{button_text}</a>
</div>  
</body> 
</html>
```

And i want to propagate these `{placeholders}` with user entered details (via a form) can i get the template i want, take the placeholder names and generate the form based on names of the placeholders in the chosen template?

so for the form above it would make this and adding it to my `pagebuilder.php :` in site-root

```
<input type="text" name="page_meta_title"required>
<input type="text" name="header"required>
<input type="text" name="page_text"required>
<input type="text" name="link_url"required>
<input type="text" name="button_text"required>
```

The user can then submit the form (with their own values placing the placeholders) which zips the html and other resources for them to download.  Note i have already made the code that does this part fully working.

End result:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>User Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
</head> 
<body> 
<div class="content-wrap">
<h3>User Title</h3>
<p>User contact</p>
<a href="#">you get the picture</a>
</div>  
</body> 
</html>
```

Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me, i'm new to PHP so there's probably a better way, hope this helps anyone else that has had the same issue, thanks:

**Add File Path and Get template**

```
 $tpl_file =  'dir/template.html'; #where the page template with place holders is
 $subject = file_get_contents($tpl_file); #get template as string
```

**Find Place holders form Template**

```
preg_match_all("/(?<={).*?(?=})/", $subject, $matches); # Search for {}     


        $arrlength = count($matches[0]); # Get how many items in array.
        for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) { #counting
        $place_name = str_replace ( "_" , "&nbsp;" , $matches[0][$x] ); #Create readible name _ to space.
```

if `{placeholder}` has the `page_` in it then generate an textarea

```
    if (preg_match("/page_/i", $matches[0][$x])) {
        echo '<label class="form_label" for="'.$matches[0][$x].'">'.$place_name.'</label>';
        echo '<textarea id="'.$matches[0][$x].'" name="'.$matches[0][$x].'" class="multi temp_preview" placeholder="'.$place_name.'"required></textarea><br>';

    }
```

if not generate an `input`

```
    else {
        echo '<label class="form_label" for="'.$matches[0][$x].'">'.$place_name.'</label>';
        echo '<input type="text" id="'.$matches[0][$x].'" name="'.$matches[0][$x].'" class="single temp_preview" placeholder="'.$place_name.'" required>'.'<br>';
    }}#end
```

Done, your form based on `{placeholders}` from a .html file is done.